# Any images of baby Buddleia globosa

Tags: identification

About three months ago I purchased some Buddleia globosa seeds and planted these in pots comprising fertiliser, but so far there is no obvious sign that any have actually appeared.

I say "obvious" because in the meantime loads of small round leaved weeds (clover, I think) have been popping up, almost from the first day. To start with, I carefully nipped these out so they would not crowd out the Buddleia if and when these finally deigned to appear.

But suspecting I may have been inadvertently weeding the Buddleia themselves, I decided to stop this weeding and let the Buddleia take their chances.

In a couple of the pots I have seen small pointy-leaved saplings which look different to the rest of the pesky weeds, and their leaves are more what I would expect a Buddleia (with its long leaves) to resemble.

So in summary, I wondered if anyone could point me to an image of a newly germinated Buddleia globosa plant.

While we're on the subject, does anyone know what kind of soil suits them best? I suspect the fertiliser I used may have been too rich or the wrong Ph, because the seed packets said they should sprout within about 30 days.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Why don't you post a picture of your "suspects" instead and let the comunity have a look?

Answer (score 3):

Rather than us scouring the internet via Google for images of seedlings of this plant, its probably better if you can upload a pic of your own seedlings for people to examine.

Otherwise, bear in mind two things - first, seeds do better planted in something called seed and cutting compost, which is formulated specially for better germination with very little fertilizer, and from which seedlings should be transplanted once they have 2 sets of true leaves; high levels of fertilizer may discourage germination or growth of seedlings. Second, the first two 'leaves' which appear are not true leaves, they're almost always round, and are just the cotyledons - the first true leaves will be what appears next, so its difficult to know what's germinated when only the cotyledons are present.

Comment: Thanks for the replies so far. I'll take a couple of pics and post these in a day or two.

Comment: @JohnRRamsden Great! We'll look forward to seeing what they look like!